# AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators'

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm receiving this code when launchign this jupyter code,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d90e432a5dde> in <module>
      2 from sklearn import tree
      3 plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))
----> 4 tree.plot_tree(regressor.estimators[0],feature_names=X_train.columns, filled=True)

AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators'

<Figure size 2880x2880 with 0 Axes>
```

This is the line causing the problem,

```
   "source": [
    "#validation of the algorithm\n",
    "from sklearn import tree\n",
    "plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))\n",
    "tree.plot_tree(regressor.estimators[0],feature_names=X_train.columns, filled=True)"
   ]
```

Any help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it does not contain an attribute `estimators`. It *does* contain [`estimators_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html), so you could try:

```
   "source": [
    "#validation of the algorithm\n",
    "from sklearn import tree\n",
    "plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))\n",
    "tree.plot_tree(regressor.estimators_[0],feature_names=X_train.columns, filled=True)"
   ]
```